# How to create new folder with FolderPicker

Tags: directory, picker

Im missing the function to create a new folders by using the Folder-(or File)Picker in Windows 8 (Metro) Apps (C#, XAML).

Background-Information:

My app downloads some Images from a server and I would choose the destination-folder with the aid of the FolderPicker. If the appropriate folder not exists, I want to create it, like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sdEH.jpg

Is this possible?